# Need to extract only integers from string in textarea, then move the result to another textarea

Tags: javascript

I have textarea:
`type="text" value="H0???"` which I cant change.

`H` & `0` are already filled in chars -predefined so users input only `3` random numbers after that. I need to extract those three numbers from that field (excluding "H" and also the leading "0").
so lets say input is like: H0987 (textarea that user fills in).
I need to have a `click` button which will execute extraction to another `text area`. Result has to be as in example `987`.

Advanced #1 question :) if anyone bothers..:
Better output would be to add comma ":" after the numbers as well so my desired output would be "987:" after the click.

Advanced #2 question :) if anyone bothers..:
when 987: is extracted to new textarea, I need then fill in also another 3 numbers based on 3 dropdowns they chose respectively.

dropdown has 3 options (lets say some colors)

dropdown has 3 options (lets say some other strings)

dropdown has 3 options (lets say some other strings)

so is there a way to add also after `"extracted numbers" + ":" + "some1.dropdownoption_option" + "some2.dropdownoption_option" + "some3.dropdownoption_option"` ?

Desired output: `987:123` where 1, 2, 3 after : represents the options users picked in dropdown. Not values themself in the option menu but assigned numbers to those options which in result are seen as numbers.

I prefer javascript as rest of my code is running that.

Thank you very much. This community is awesome.

Comment: Can you post the code? Makes it easier to help resolve your issue.

Comment: community is awesome no doubt. But people here love to see efforts. can you post code you have written till now for it. would be encouraging for me to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working based on site examples. There was no need for dropdown calls as I stated in the question but I needed checkboxes instead. Also, string was starting with "B" so I had to check actually for last char with (value.length-1). Also I used checkbox instead of button. Code can definitely be improved.

```
<input id="hostname" name="hostname" type="text" value="BR0???" class="hostname"/>
<input id="comtest" name="comtest" type="text" class="commmunity"/>
<input id="comm_check1" name="comm_check1" type="checkbox"  onchange="f_set_comm()"/>

function f_set_comm() {

  //extract integers    
  var value = document.getElementById("hostname").value;
  var numbers = value.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);

  //add :9
  document.getElementById("comtest").value = numbers; 
  document.getElementById("comtest").value = document.getElementById("comtest").value + ":9";

  //check type and add 1 or 2 based on last char A or B in hostname
  if (value.substring(value.length-1)== "A")
    document.getElementById("comtest").value = document.getElementById("comtest").value + "1";

  if (value.substring(value.length-1)== "B")
    document.getElementById("comtest").value = document.getElementById("comtest").value + "2";

    if (!((value.substring(value.length-1)== "A")) && (!(value.substring(value.length-1)== "B")))
       document.getElementById("comtest").value = document.getElementById("comtest").value + "0";

      //remove all strings if unchecked
  if (!document.getElementById("comm_check1").checked)
    document.getElementById('comtest').value = '';

}
```